# Java 5-compiled binaries on Java 1.3 runtime

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility

May I know if there are any issues running a Java 5-compiled code (with Java 1.3 source/target compliance) on a Java 1.3 JVM?

I know this is quite odd, but most of our customers are on Java 5 but we are restricted by a few still on Java 1.3 due to conditions beyond our control.  Our CI tool uses Java 5 compiler but we set our source and target compliance to Java 1.3 for backward compatibility.  We are not using Java 1.3 for CI because there are unit tests that does not compile on 1.3.

Will this be an issue?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
- Paul

Comment: **1.4** is obsolete.  There comes a time when supporting the older JREs will cost more in maintenance, than can be earned from those customers.

Comment: This is true, Andrew.  We have some rigid constraints.  Some of our customers are using handheld devices where only Java 1.3 is supported.  Either Oracle would add JVM support to this devices, or our customers would have to upgrade their devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get the compiler to check that source in your app. only uses 1.3 methods is to specify a `-bootclasspath` pointing to a 1.3 rt.jar.  Note you can get that from a 1.3 JRE, it does not require a 1.3 SDK/compiler.  Of course, specify a `-target` of 1.3.

Comment: +1 Here is [a cross-compilation example from Oracle's docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-example).

Comment: There is no issue compiling our source code at the moment.  I'm just concerned if there will be runtime issues.  So far we have not encountered any, but I have not seen any formal documentation from Sun or Oracle that backs this.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem you will have is that while the JVM generated byte code will be compliant with 1.3, the JDK you're compiling against is Java 5. It is very easy to use a class, or more likely, a method that exists in Java 5, but not in the 1.3 JDK. This code will compile fine but will fail to run on a 1.3 runtime.

Comment: Interesting. I would assume that `-target 1.3` would refuse to compile or at least give a warning if a class newer than 1.3 was referenced. Without that, `-target 1.3` seems far less usefull.

Comment: @Asaph: I can tell you from long experience that use of classes and methods which are from a new JDK version will be your most significant pitfall in using a newer JDK to compile to an older target.  I actually *now* compile all my code to 1.5 and use retroweaver to weave some applications back to 1.4 or 1.3, so I can use the compiler enhancements and other goodies in 1.5.

Comment: @Asaph: no you have to give the compiler a 1.3 rt.jar to have these checks. `-target` is mostly about class-file format and some language features.

Comment: Yes. It looks like you're right. People [have felt this pain](http://madbean.com/2006/target14/). But there is a solution. See @Andrew Thompson's answer.

Comment: @Will Development is setting their IDE source compliance to 1.3 so this should be able to flush out Java 5-specific code.  Our ant script is also setting -source -target options to 1.3.  My concern is at runtime.  So in production, we have 1.3 byte code (compiled with a Java 5 compiler) running on a 1.3 JVM.  I'm interested in finding out if -target 1.3 is sufficient and no runtime compatibility issues will be encountered.

Comment: @Paul - As @Andrew mentions, while the syntax setting prevents language level features from creeping in, nothing (save changing the jar classpath) prevents you from using classes only available in a new JRE.

Comment: @Will you are right. This is the kind of issue i'm interested in finding out. Do you know of anything specific? Or can you point me to a link?